# Function Context Changes and Cannot Recognize Local Variables

Tags: angular, angular2-services, typescript2.0, angular5

I am using a data service to pass data between sibling components.
I am facing a problem in the data service where **the context of the function changes** when **accessing the array and pushing data** into there.

```
@Injectable()
export class PassDataProxy {

passedData = [];

constructor(
) { }

pushPassedData = (input) => {

    //I can see the data passed into the function from this console
    console.log("To push: " + JSON.stringify(input));

    //This is where things go south
    this.passedData.push(input);
}

getPassedData(input) {
    return Observable.of(this.passedData);
}

clearPassedData() {
    this.passedData = null;
}

}
```

I injected the dependency from the child component and called `pushPassedData` function, and I can see the data is passed successfully to the function from the console. But when you access the `passedData` array and run `push` function, it gives this error:

[image: Error message]

My guess is that the context is changed and it cannot recognize the array anymore so i used arrow function instead of normal function. Even then, I still had this error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The error indicates that `this.passedData` is null. Are you sure that `clearPassedData` is not called before `pushPassedData`?

Comment: OMG Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Yes it is. I realized assigning it to null makes it lose its array properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I called `clearPassedData` before calling `pushPassedData`.

There is nothing wrong with that but `clearPassedData` function should look like

```
clearPassedData() {
    this.passedData = [];
}
```

I realized I was setting the variable to `null` instead of `[]` so it lost its array properties.